# How to use Cells(x,y) or range(cells) to input values from one cell to another?

Tags: excel, vba

The values in cells SecondSetCellInputtedNameCTR ("Toyota Camry"), SecondSetCellInputtedLengthCTR ("10"/integer), and SecondSetCellInputtedStartDateCTR ("2020-04") arent being placed in the cells SecondSetOutputNameCTR, SecondSetCelloutputLengthCTR , and SecondSetCelloutputStartDateCTR  respectively.

I am getting empty cells for the output ones even though the code says otherwise. [image]

**I have tried:**

1)

```vb
SecondSetCellInputtedNameCTR = Cells(SecondSetInputtedRowNumCTR, SecondSetInputtedColNumName).Value 'only thing that will change is the CTR which is row entry
SecondSetCellInputtedStartDateCTR = Cells(SecondSetInputtedRowNumCTR, SecondSetInputtedColStartDate).Value 'only thing that will change is the CTR which is row entry
SecondSetCellInputtedLengthCTR = Cells(SecondSetInputtedRowNumCTR, SecondSetInputtedColLength).Value 'only thing that will change is the CTR which is row entry
SecondSetOutputNameCTR = Cells(SecondSetOutputRowNumCTR, CellOutputNameCol)
SecondSetCelloutputLengthCTR = Cells(SecondSetOutputRowNumCTR, CellOutputLengthCol)
SecondSetCelloutputStartDateCTR = Cells(SecondSetOutputRowNumCTR, CellOutputStartDateCol)
```

2) Notice how the `.value` is taken away:

```vb
SecondSetCellInputtedNameCTR = Cells(SecondSetInputtedRowNumCTR, SecondSetInputtedColNumName) 'only thing that will change is the CTR which is row entry
SecondSetCellInputtedStartDateCTR = Cells(SecondSetInputtedRowNumCTR, SecondSetInputtedColStartDate) 'only thing that will change is the CTR which is row entry
SecondSetCellInputtedLengthCTR = Cells(SecondSetInputtedRowNumCTR, SecondSetInputtedColLength) 'only thing that will change is the CTR which is row entry
SecondSetOutputNameCTR = Cells(SecondSetOutputRowNumCTR, CellOutputNameCol)
SecondSetCelloutputLengthCTR = Cells(SecondSetOutputRowNumCTR, CellOutputLengthCol)
SecondSetCelloutputStartDateCTR = Cells(SecondSetOutputRowNumCTR, CellOutputStartDateCol)`
```

*In the above section I show what each of these terms equal to.*

`SecondSetInputtedRowNumCTR` is the Row Number that is being looked at from the second dataset in Column E.

```vb
Do While SecondSetInputtedRowNumCTR < LengthSecondSet + 1
    SecondSetOutputNameCTR = SecondSetCellInputtedNameCTR
    SecondSetCelloutputLengthCTR = SecondSetCellInputtedLengthCTR
    SecondSetCelloutputStartDateCTR = SecondSetCellInputtedStartDateCTR
    SecondSetInputtedRowNumCTR = SecondSetInputtedRowNumCTR + 1
Loop
```

**I expect to get:**
`SecondSetOutputNameCTR cell` to be "Toyota Camry"
`SecondSetCelloutputLengthCTR`  cell to be "10", and
`SecondSetCellInputtedStartDateCTR` cell to be "2020-04"

**I am actually getting:** empty values for all of output cells.

Why is that?

Comment: Your screenshot has `FirstSetCellInputtedLengthCTR` called out, is that a mistake? Also, qualify which `Worksheet` those `Cells` are on, otherwise the `ActiveSheet` is implied. If I can also suggest shorter variable names, that might make your code easier to read.

Comment: What have you declared `SecondSetCellInputtedNameCTR` as? Is it meant to be a `Range` and you are missing `Set`? Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the code module and declare all your variables.

Comment: Nothing in the body of the `Do...While` loop refers to `SecondSetInputtedRowNumCTR` except for the line which adds 1 to its value. The expressions on the right-hand side like `SecondSetCellInputtedNameCTR` won't automatically change just because the counter increases

Comment: Generous use of `Debug.Print` will verify whether "the code says otherwise."

Comment: coming from another angle - yur code is hard to read.. suggest making your names shorter/condensed.. StartDate = SDate etc etc etc etc....